Dynamically resizing a section on my webpage to match the section right next to it
Apologies if my question is too naive. I'm new to front end development. On my page, I have two sections, one is the sectionA and the other one is the sectionB. The dimensions of sectionA are 828x161, and the dimensions of sectionB are 828x271. I have two issues here:
SectionA should dynamically have the same dimensions as sectionB. How to do that in css?
The ratio of sectionA to sectionB in the column should be 40:60. How should be sections-container class look like to achieve this?
<grid className="sections-container">
  <gridToken=>
    {/* Content of Section A */}
  </gridToken>
  <gridToken>
    {/* Content of Section B */}
  </gridToken>
</grid>

I've tried out a few things and they don't seem to be working. Any help would be appreciated.

Use flex property. See this doc


.container {
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    display: flex;
}

.section-a {
    flex: 0.4; 

    background-color: coral;
}

.section-b {
    flex: 0.6;

    background-color: blueviolet;
}

/* Below code will center the content inside section a and b */
.section-a,
.section-b {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
<div class="container">
            <div class="section-a">Section A</div>
            <div class="section-b">Section B</div>
</div>




Flex would help here. Why did you comment that the flex value is between 0 and 1? It could be any positive number, even greater than 1.

It was a bit confusing, but thanks—I’ve resolved it now.

Thanks for your answer. The ratio works as expected. However, I see that the container height and width have been specified here. Is there a way that sectionA, whose height is lesser than sectionB, could dynamically resize itself to the height of sectionB here? Like one section resizes itself to the max of height of two sections?
